# `Export to csv` button missing in Neo4j 3.x browser

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv

Dear neo4j gurus and users, here is my situation.
Since graphConnect in London I've been using version 3.0. Some days ago I had the need to export a table result in csv, I hit the "save to file" button in top-right of the browser result frame, but only the `export to json` option was there. `Export to csv` is missing.

I did the following as a test:

- install new **neo4j 3.0.0** instance, create some data, return as table => the `export to csv` button is **missing**;
- install new **neo4j 3.0.1** instance, create some data, return as table => the `export to csv` button is **missing**;
- install new **neo4j 2.3.3** instance, create some data, return as table => the `export to csv` button is **working**;

I tested the same above with Oracle and OpenJDK java-8, with no difference.

I had the same behavior using `neo4j-shell-tools`, which works (I tested `export-graphml` command) only in version 2.3.3. (I opened an issue for that at https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/issues/88).

I'm running neo in my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.
Is there anything I can do to help you answer this? Any log/debug information that could be useful? Do you see the `export csv` button in your neo4j 3.x browsers?

Comment: Menu "Export to a file" -> "Export SWC" - present (OSX Safari && Windows Chrome). Maybe this is a problem in the web browser? Try a different web browser (on a different computer? another operating system?).

Comment: You are right, I was using chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit). In firefox I can see the `export to csv` button!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the web browser: try a different web browser (if do not help - on the other operating system). And update the version of the web browser to the latest stable.

Comment: I also updated my ubuntu chrome to latest Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit), but still no `export to csv` is there. I'll go for firefox for now!

Comment: You can look in the chrome console - whether there are any errors in `neo4j-browser`?